# Phpunit marks test as "risky" when calling showAction method of ExceptionController

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, twig

When trying to test a class which calls the `showAction` method of `ExceptionController` (class  located at `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Tests/Controller/ExceptionControllerTest.php`) it marks as "**risky**" the test, saying:

> Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

example code:

```
    $request = Request::create('whatever', 'GET');
    $request->attributes->set('showException', false);

    $exception = FlattenException::create(new \Exception(), 404);

    $controller = new ExceptionController($twig, true);

    $response = $controller->showAction($request, $exception, null);

    // some assertions....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to solve the problem, the header `X-Php-Ob-Level` of the request should be set to `1`:

```
$request->headers->set('X-Php-Ob-Level', 1);
```

example code:

```
$request = Request::create('whatever', 'GET');
$request->headers->set('X-Php-Ob-Level', 1);
$request->attributes->set('showException', false);

$exception = FlattenException::create(new \Exception(), 404);

$controller = new ExceptionController($twig, true);

$response = $controller->showAction($request, $exception, null);

// some assertions....
```